# Change template color in Luna Admin Template

Tags: html, css, templates, admin, responsive

I have got an admin template whose background color is dark and I have spent hours to figure out how can I change its color to light/white.

The template can be found [here](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/luna-responsive-admin-theme-WB0J69TPB).

I have also posted a query at the sales page but it is taking much long to get a reply.

Comment: show some code .

Comment: Check theme CSS and change colors: http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.3/styles/style.css

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.content {
    background:#fff;
}
```